# Vert.x Event Bus to retain message

Tags: vert.x, event-bus, vertx-verticle

I am following [the vertx sockjs example](https://github.com/kliakos/vertx-sockjs-example) to transfer data over the SockJS event bus bridge.

The sending code:

```
eventBus.publish(ebAddress, data);
```

The consumer code:

```js
var eb = new EventBus("http://localhost:8088/eventbus");

  eb.onopen = function () {
    eb.registerHandler("/ebaddress", function (err, msg) {
      var str = "<code>" + msg.body + "</code><br>";
      console.log(str);
    })
  }
```

The first client works fine. However, for the second connected client, since it is subscribing the same eb address, it cannot get the most current data that has been sent to the first client. It won't be an issue if the data is coming in fast. But if the time interval between data points are long, the second client will have no data for a long time until the next new data point arrive.

So, is the event bus of Vert.x able to retain message so that whenever a new client connects, it can get the most recent data right away?

I am pretty new to Vert.x, so any comments will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not think Vert.x Eventbus allows you to do that. As a work around, you can create a consumer on the server that subscribes to the topic and retains the recent N messages. On the client side, the client consumer issues a request (point-to-point) to the consumer on the server to retrieve the recent messages before listening to the main topic.

Comment: @suenda that sounds like a plan too. By point-to-point, are you talking about something like a RESTful API?

Comment: No, by point-to-point I mean you send a message via method `.send()` to a specific component via EventBus. See documentation for detail https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_the_event_bus_api

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: no, Vert.x EventBus doesn't persist messages. Nor does it able to replay them, for that reason. It just that: a bus to send events on. After all, when you write in JavaScript `element.on("click", function() {})`, you don't usually expect to receive all previous clicks, right?

But, it doesn't mean it's not possible.
In your JavaScript:

```
eb.onopen = function () {
    // On connect your client asks on a different channel to get some previously stored messages
    eb.send("/replay", {count: 10}, null, function(err, msg) {
       // Populate your code
    });
    // Continue here as usual
    eb.registerHandler("/ebaddress", function (err, msg) {
      // Something happens here
    })
  }
```

Of course on your server side you'll need to

1. Persist some amount of messages, either in-memory or in some storage of your choice
2. Listen to this new `/replay` channel
3. Use `.send()` to reply to specific client with previous messages